# Call to a member function notify() on string

Tags: laravel, notifications

' I am new in Laravel and I am trying to send notification but it shows an error (Call to a member function notify() on string)'

```
$discussion->user['email']->notify(new newReplyAdded($discussion));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use notify() on a model, not on a string. Like below

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->notify(..)
```

And you have to use Notifiable trait in you model like

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
    ..........
}
```

In your case, you can try this

```
$discussion->user->notify(new newReplyAdded($discussion));
```